# Cannot get full dom content from page

Tags: javascript, zombie.js

When i try to get full dom content from xvideos (meaby it site is not the best example but i cant find any more at now) browser.html() return only last div element of dom. I think it is the last rendered div by javascript on page but i am not sure.

```
var zombie = require("zombie");                                                                                                    

zombie.visit("http://www.xvideos.com/", function (err, browser) {
  console.log(browser.html());                        
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`browser.html()` does return whole page. Quick test showed that fetching xvideos.com with zombie result in some "stub" page.

It's just a theory, but probably guys on xvideos use some browser detection script and return stub page for any browser (UserAgent) that is different than most common ones. It's probably a security measure to protect themselfs against crawlers.